# mongo db query to update document containing map object

Tags: mongodb

I have below object in mongodb.

```
db.agedClientPosition.find().pretty(); {
    "_id": ObjectId("596b0f02abc9b006c7de33fb"),
    "_class": "org.maruti.mfm.data.entity.AgedClientPosition",
    "ageBucket": {
        "03-Jul-2017": 3482.896,
        "05-Jul-2017": 2403.1168,
        "10-Jul-2017": 299.4155
    },
    "divPayoutBucket": {

    },
    "createdOn": ISODate("2017-07-16T07:00:18.769Z"),
    "modifiedOn": ISODate("2017-07-16T07:01:29.221Z"),
    "client": DBRef("client", ObjectId("59544747e6de8f0328c9e8bb")),
    "folio": DBRef("folio", ObjectId("5954475fe6de8f0328c9e8bc")),
    "scheme": DBRef("scheme", ObjectId("5953c0c0e6de8f024753e3e1"))
}
```

and for all the ageBucket I want to increment date by 1 day.

Can I achieve this using mondodb query?

Comment: It's a "key". You cannot atomically increment a "key". You can only replace the whole object or the key at that given path. Ideally this should be an array of values, and indeed use actual `Date` objects. Those you could actually increment. You also are still using `DBRef`, so you actually have bigger problems.